# R Markdown message=FALSE still spits out warnings

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My R Markdown chunk header is as follows:

````
```{r fluid_flowrate, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.height = 4, fig.width = 10}
# followed by my ggplot2 code
```
````

yet I knit to HTML and I get the proper plot, accompanied by this warning, printed twice:

```
## Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
## Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I thought `message=FALSE` forced warnings to disappear. Why are they appearing?

Comment: You need to use the option `warning=FALSE`.  See Yihui's website for a full listing of chunk options: [https://yihui.name/knitr/options/](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/)

Comment: The `message` option turns off messages, and the `warning` option turns off warnings. A message is helpful information, such as what additional packages are being loaded or what API a function uses. A warning is something that may signal a problem, such as missing factors generating `NA`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the following to the chunk options

```
warning=FALSE
```

it will [prevents warnings that are generated by code from appearing in the finished](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html#chunk-options)

Comment: You may wish to improve this answer by expanding on the details and providing a basic example. As it is currently, it is better suited as a comment.